# REGEXP_LIKE: Character positioning?

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have the following field:

```
msg
----
2015-07-22-06.53.32
CIPIRDSR:XQ040 CHANGE
2015-07-22-06.53.42
1
reg
```

I am trying to extract the datetime only. I was using

```
WHERE NOT REGEXP_LIKE (msg, '^[[:digit:]]+$')
```

however, that doesn't quite do it what I want it to. It still returns more than the datetime. Can you help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to extract the date time, then use the date time format you are looking for:

```
where regexp_like(msg, '^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}[.][0-9]{2}[.][0-9]{2}$')
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, this is perfect!